# Pointer to a class member function

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, member

Let's say, I've two  classes

```
class A
{
  public:
    void foo( /* ............. */ );
};

class B
{
   public:
      void bar();
};
```

I want to know, if it's even possible to pass to the `foo` method a pointer of `bar` method, store it in `A` and run `bar` later from `A`. I should say, that `A` won't know, what class `bar` is a member of!

I'd appreciate much if you show me the syntax or some link with not that complicated description of the topic.

**DESCRIPTION**
I'm designing an `observer` pattern for C++. I want to subscribe `B` to some events of `A`. e.g. this code should be in an instance of `B`

```
   // pseudo code    
   A* observable = new A();
   observable->addEventListener ( 'eventTitle' , functionName );
```

And when `eventTitle` occurs `A` calls `functionName` of `B`

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and why do you need this? I think there are better ways to solve your problem or what ever you want...

Comment: Please post a pseudo-code use case example of the desired behaviour.

Comment: Does `bar()` have to be a member of class B?

Comment: Do you really need to pass a pointer-to-member-function?, you might solve your problem just using polymorfism. What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: If you are using C++11, you can pass it as std::function<void()>.

Comment: Added a comment to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a couple of methods how to call a pointer to member function, hiding it's origin:

- Use std::function and std::bind:

  ```
  class B {    
      double Sqrt(int what) { return std::sqrt((double)what); }
  };   

  // in A:
  std::tr1::function<double (int)> fn; 
  fn = std::tr1::bind(&B::Sqrt, &operations, std::tr1::placeholders::_1);
  fn(3.1415);
  ```
- Use a functor, which will wrap the pointer to member function and the object, on which it's to be called, togeter. (This is a bit complicated, though, and in principle is just a subset of what std::function does).
- Derive B from an abstract interface IFn and pass B as IFn reference to Foo. Foo will know what to call - a virtual Do() function of the interface.

Answer (score 2):

That won't work unless `bar` is declared as a `static` member of `B`. You should take into account that you would need an instance of `B` in order to call any non-static methods.

(Check the [C++ FAQ chapter on pointer-to-member-functions](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html) for a deeper explanation.)

**UPDATE**: if you want to implement an observer pattern, you can declare an interface (pure abstract class), say `Observer`, that `A` knows and use pointer-to-member-functions to map your events to the corresponding `Observer` methods.

Example:

```
   A observable;
   observable.addEventListener ( 'eventTitle' , &B::functionName );
   B observer;
   observable.registerObserver(&observer);
```

Comment: An instance of `B`, in fact (I guess it was just a typo).

Answer (score 2):

How can `A` use a member function of `B` without knowing anything about it? To call it, you need an object, which has to be o type `B` (or subtype), so `A` must have this knowledge.

If you make `bar()` a static function, you can use regular function pointer (`void (*)()`) or `std::function<void ()>` (`boost::function` for older C++) - of which I would strongly recommend the latter.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like:

```
class A
{
public:
  void foo( /* ............. */ );
  void SetObs(CObs *pObs)
  {
    m_pObs = pObs;
  }

private:
  CObs *m_pObs;
};

class B : public class CObs
{
public:
  virtual void bar();
};

class CObs
{
public:
  virtual void bar() = 0;
};
```

And whenever you need bar() function call m_pObs->bar(). Also derive all slasses like B from CObs and override the function bar().

Comment: This won't compile: `A` doesn't know `CObs`. If you declare `CObs` before `A`, there might be no need to pass a pointer-to member-function to `foo`, and I'm not sure that is a feasible escenario for the OP.